# Uncaught ReferenceError: [ function_name ] is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I have an upload file button.

[image]

**Note** : `onclick="getFile()"`

So the `getFile()` function will be call when the btn is clicked.

---

## HTML

```
<center>
    <form action="#type your action here" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm">
        <div id="yourBtn" onclick="getFile()">click to upload a file</div>
        <div style='height: 0px;width: 0px; overflow:hidden;'>
            <input id="upfile" type="file" value="upload" onchange="sub(this)" />
        </div>
    </form>
</center>
```

---

## CSS

```
#yourBtn {
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    font-family: calibri;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px dashed #BBB;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #DDD;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

---

## JS

```
 $(window).load( function () {
     
     // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images  
     function getFile() {
         document.getElementById("upfile").click();
     }

     function sub(obj) {
         var file = obj.value;
         var fileName = file.split("\\");
         document.getElementById("yourBtn").innerHTML = fileName[fileName.length - 1];
         document.myForm.submit();
         event.preventDefault();
     }

 });
```

---

I've tried placing all my JS code within the `$(window).load( function (){});`

I kept getting error on my console say `Uncaught ReferenceError: getFile is not defined`

Why is that, and how do I fix it?

If you need, I've put together [my FIDDLE here](https://jsfiddle.net/b5wd0379/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions you call from `onXyz` attribute-style handlers must be globals, but your `getFile` function isn't global, it's only accessible from within your `load` callback. (This is good. Globals are a Bad Thing.<sup>(tm)</sup>)

Your best bet is to hook up the handler from within `load` (and the same for `sub`):

```
<div id="yourBtn">click to upload a file</div>
<!-- ... -->
<input id="upfile" type="file" value="upload" />
```

Then:

```
$(window).load( function () {

    $("#yourBtn").on("click", getFile);
    $("#upfile").on("change", sub);

    // ...

});
```

---

Off-topic, but you might also consider using something other than `$(window).load(...)`, which happens **very** late in the page loading process. If you control where your `script` tags go, just put your `script` tag at the very end of the file, just before the closing `</body>` tag, and change

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // ...
});
```

to

```
(function() {
    // ...
})();
```

If you don't control where your `script` tag goes, then a second-best solution is to use jQuery's `ready` callback:

```
$(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `$(window).load` handler so the function is in the global scope, and it will work.

When the function is inside the `load` handler it's local to that scope only and can't be accessed from inline handlers that require the function to be in the global scope.

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/b5wd0379/1/)

Also note that jsFiddle wraps the function in it's own `onload` handler unless you change the dropdown on the left to `"nowrap in ***"`.

You should be using jQuery's event handlers instead.